# IOS Test.app file is not installing on simulator

Tags: ios

I was struck at installing `Test.app` file in simulator i tried in different methods but its not working.

Please give proper solution. I am followed this
`Library-->Application support--->iPhone` simulator, but I didn't found iPhone simulator in my Library folder.

Comment: Have u installed Xcode from App store or from .dmg?

Comment: @UmaMadhavi I installed using .dmg..IS there any problem doing this way

Comment: @RohitPradhan no problem if it is not installed in applications means you might not found simulator .

Comment: It is happening with me to..I am not getting simulator downloaded.I need to explicitly download from Download Simulators

Comment: @UmaMadhavi ya  i installed  xcode in Applications only but unable to find out .Any way please guide me how to install .app file in simulators and how to work with them

Comment: @RohitPradhan guide me how to install the .app file in simulator and how to work with that mainly i was struck at installing .app file in simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find in below path

Library -> Developer -> Xcode -> DerivedData > Select your project -> Build -> Products -> Debug-iphonesimulator

Comment: thank you sir i followed you i got Debug-iPhonesimulator fine what to do next please guide me.